# Como manipular strings com ".find"

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Eu posso usar o ".find" para fazer o programa buscar alguma palavra dentro de um texto digitado e dizer se existe ou não existe?(true or false) e em que linha do texto está localizado,se não, qual comando uso para fazer isso?
O que já tenho até agora:

```
a = str(input())
#output: Criando um exemplo.
print(a.find('exemplo'))
```

Comment: Para podermos te ajudar, [forneça um código Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5):

O método `find` deve ser utilizado apenas se te interessar a posição da ocorrência na *string*, isto é, saber em que parte da *string* foi encontrado o valor desejado. Se a intenção é apenas verificar se for encontrado, o ideal é utilizar o operador `in`:

```
texto = input()
if "exemplo" in texto:
    print("Encontrou")
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/8MLBer) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NNrV/0)</sup>

Lembrando que no Python 3, o retorno da função `input` já é uma *string*, então não há necessidade de convertê-la novamente.

Se realmente for interessante saber em qual posição ocorreu o valor desejado, é possível fazer algo como:

```
texto = input()
index = texto.find("exemplo")
if index >= 0:
    print("Encontrou na posição %d" % index)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/IGDWmb) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NNrb/0)</sup>

Comment: Existe alguma forma de sinalizar em que linha a palavra está, no caso de textos grandes?

Comment: @LucasSouza sim. Se esse texto está em uma variável, o mais simples seria efetuar um `split` nas quebras de linha, `\n`, percorrê-las e verificar linha a linha se possui o conteúdo desejado.